# Rackspace Cloud Sites API (Not Cloud Servers)

Tags: rackspace, stats

I'm looking for a way to pull data from my Rackspace Cloud SITES account. The data I want to pull is bandwidth, diskspace, and compute cycles (all available from control panel). I'd like to set up my own warning system, to be notified if I'm close to my limits on any given month.

Does anyone know of a way/API to do this?

Comment: I'm interested in this as well because I want to start scripting site creation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've asked the same question myself of Rackspace support. They said:

> ... We are working on a new
>   stats system that will be customer
>   facing, however I do not have any firm
>   ETA on that project.

I was also looking for hourly stats on bandwith et al, and they could not do that either. They do have daily numbers, but you have to raise a ticket and have them send you a spreadsheet with them.

**EDIT:** I've just logged in today and have seen (in the menu under YourAccount/Reports) new per-billing cycle graphs of CloudSites stats for bandwidth, CC's, disk-space etc.  I'm really not sure at all of the numbers that are shown there, but it's a start.  No exporting of the numbers from there either that I can see on the page.

Comment: Thanks, Alister. So, have you been happy with Cloud Sites? I'm getting ready to move from my dedicated Linux server to this platform.

Comment: I think it's better suited to occasionally changing static content - we use if for a lot of Flash and images. Big or non-changing files will be moving increasingly to CloudFiles.
While it can do PHP scripts, it's not optimised for it, and I'm trying to move any heavy scripts to my own server.
One thing we really found it was not good at was very large directories of images - that blows out the compute cycles fetching them. I moved them to CloudFiles as well (over 600,000 files in a directory).

Comment: have you any benchmarks or data to prove this claim? I just installed Wordpress on cloudsites and ran Apache Bench 3 times against it: ab -n 500 -c 100 deskhead.com/index.php; The result returned: 24req/sec the first run, then 58req/sec, then 72req/sec. These strike me as fairly respectable numbers, your thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

It's in the planning stage (whatever that means).

You can up-vote it on their [feedback site](http://feedback.rackspacecloud.com/forums/71021-product-feedback/suggestions/998005-create-a-cloud-site-api).